# Multiple Notifications Not Firing

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I'm scheduling two notifications as shown below.  The app is a long-lived app.  One local notification is scheduled to run every hour.  The other is scheduled to run once per day.  Only the second scheduled notification (the hourly notifcation) fires.

```
- (void)scheduleNotification
{
LogInfo(@"IN scheduleNotification - DELETEYESTERDAY NOTIFICATION SCHEDULED.");

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDictionary *deleteDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"DeleteYesterday"
                                                          forKey:@"DeleteYesterday"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

[components setDay: day];
[components setMonth: month];
[components setYear: year];
[components setHour: 00];
[components setMinute: 45];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

notif.fireDate = dateToFire;
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
notif.userInfo = deleteDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

and then I schedule this after above:

```
- (void)scheduleHeartBeat
{
LogInfo(@"IN scheduleHeartBeat - HEARTBEAT NOTIFICATION SCHEDULED.");

UILocalNotification *heartbeat = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDictionary *heartbeatDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"HeartBeat"
                                                     forKey:@"HeartBeat"];

heartbeat.userInfo = heartbeatDict;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

[components setDay: day];
[components setMonth: month];
[components setYear: year];
[components setHour: 00];
[components setMinute: 50];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

heartbeat.fireDate = dateToFire;
heartbeat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
heartbeat.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:heartbeat];
}
```

The above are scheduled when the app launches in the viewDidLoad of the main view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self scheduleNotification];
[self scheduleHeartBeat];

[super viewDidLoad];
//OTHER CODE HERE
}
```

Then in the appdelegate I have the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
LogInfo(@"IN didReceiveLocalNotification NOTIFICATION RECEIVED.");

NSString *notificationHeartBeat = nil;
NSString *notificationDeleteYesterday = nil;

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;    

if (notification) {
    notificationHeartBeat = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"HeartBeat"];
    notificationDeleteYesterday = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"DeleteYesterday"];
    LogInfo(@"IN didReceiveLocalNotification HEARTBEAT NOTIFICATION TYPE: %@", notificationHeartBeat);
    LogInfo(@"IN didReceiveLocalNotification DELETEYESTERDAY NOTIFICATION TYPE: %@", notificationDeleteYesterday);
}

if ([notificationHeartBeat isEqualToString:@"HeartBeat"]) {
    //CREATE THE HEARTBEAT
    LogInfo(@"CREATING THE HEARTBEAT.");
    //CALL THE FUNCTIONALITY HERE THAT CREATES HEARTBEAT.
}

if ([notificationDeleteYesterday isEqualToString:@"DeleteYesterday"]) {
    //DELETE YESTERDAYS RECORDS
    LogInfo(@"DELETING YESTERDAYS RECORDS.");

}    
}
```

The notification that is scheduled last (scheduleHeartBeat) is the only notification that is fired.
Could somebody help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified your repeat interval to `NSDayCalendarUnit`. So, your notification will be fire but at next day at specified time.

For testing purpose change your this repeat interval and check your code is working properly.

I have tested. Your code is working properly here.